# Display Attachments in Community Portal

Tags: apex, visualforce

Following line of code is being used to display an attachment in VF page.

This displays attachment in VF page in Salesforce(c.na10.visual.force.com/apex/viewDoc?q=XXX). When I use this page via communities portal(testcommunity1.force.com/test/viewDoc?q=XXX), the link below does have correct values of ID, & ContentType but attachment is not fetched.

How do I display attachment in Communities Portal?

```
<object data="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.id}" type="{!a.ContentType}"></object>
```

Note:- It is same user accessing both the URLs.

Comment: Where you able to solve this ? because whenever I try to access attachment on Community it gives me Insufficient error. Though we are able to query and fetch attachment, but unable to download/view attachments as it gives insufficient error.

Comment: @ChiragMehta have you tried the answer I have given below?

Answer (score 3):

URL above is a relative URL, which doesn't work if page is being accessed via Portal where base URL is different.

**Apex Controller:-**

```
    public String baseURL {get;set;}

    If(String.ValueOf(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()).contains('communityDomain'))
        baseURL = 'https://communityDomain.force.com/communityURL';
        //communityDomain- is domain, communityURL - is portal url
    else
        baseURL = '';
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
    <object data="{!baseURL}/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.id}" type="{!a.ContentType}"></object>
```